# contenteditable not working in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid in few columns i was having input textbox but later i have replaced input with span now i want to make span editable.
for that i have used `contenteditable="true"`

it's working separately, but when i have placed inside span it is not working

**Code**- directly i have putted `contenteditable="true"` in span

```
template: '<div class="boxGrid boxGrid-new"><span class="input-qty cost-txtcountbx spanInput form-control" contenteditable="true">#= Qty#</span></div>'
```

but not working

what can be the problem